# How do I get this to display the shell?

Tags: linux, bash

To get this code to run properly, I created a txt file named `new_user.txt` with the following format (supposed to follow /etc/passwd)

```
    doejjan:x:Doe, Jane Joe+111222:home/STUDENTS/teststu:/bin/bash
    smidjoh:x:Smith, John Jay+222333:home/STUDENTS/teststu:/bin/bash
```

I want to try to display the command that was created to show every record on the screen, below is what I have so far:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
  username=$(echo "$line" | cut -d: -f1)
  GECOS=$(echo "$line" | cut -d: -f5)
  homedir=$(echo "$line" | cut -d: -f6)
  echo "adduser -g '$GECOS' -d '$homedir' -s /bin/bash '$username'"
done < "$new_user.txt"
```

I'm getting the error in line 7 that says the following:
`.txt:No such file or directory`

Can you help me try to fix the error message? Thank you in advance.

Comment: `< "$1"` passes input to `while` from `"$1"`. The next line is treated as a command, not a heredoc

Comment: This line, `username:password:uid:gid:GECOS:homedir:she`, what is it supposed to be doing? It's interpreted as a (non-existing) command.

Comment: I meant to delete the `username:password:uid:gid:GECOS:homedir:she` section, I'm trying to figure out how to only display the command of each user.

Comment: When you mentioned heredoc, would I change the "$1" to $new_user.txt in order to display the command for each section? @jhnc

Comment: [positional parameters](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Positional-Parameters), [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion),  [redirection](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Redirecting-Input)

Comment: `$new_user` is a variable reference. Lose the dollar sign.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the error message, you can understand that the variable `new_user` must be empty. Indeed you never assign a value to this variable.

From your description, it follows that `$new_user` should expand to the value `new_user`. Say your script is called `my_script`. If you run it as

```
new_user=new_user my_script
```

the error will be gone. If the script is run most of the time on the file `new_user.txt`, you can - in your script - provide a default value for this variable:

```
: ${new_user:=new_user}
```

If you then run it as

```
my_script
```

it will pick up new_user.txt, but if you run it by

```
new_user=old_user my_script
```

it will run on old_user.txt.

BTW, I personally would prefer passing the file name to the script either via stdin or on the command line, but you have choosen to use a variable for this task, and you can do this of course, if you prefer.

Comment: I think the OP simply intended to hardcode `new_user.txt`, and didn't intend there to be a variable at all.

Comment: Perhaps, but there are plenty of other variables used in the program, and the OP at least seems to be pretty sure about what a variable is.